# Term for words such as "dognitary"

Tags: terminology

Is there a term for words that have been altered in this way?

For example, when speaking about a dignitary that is a dog, using "dognitary"

Comment: I'd just call it a [pun](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pun). Alternatively, take a leaf out of Johnson's book and call it [the lowest form of humor](http://thelowestformofhumor.blogspot.co.uk/)

Comment: That would be something of a [*trompe-l’oreille*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trompe-l'%C5%93il), *n’nest-ce pas?* :)

Answer (score 8):

It is a [portmanteau](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/portmanteau), a word formed by merging two other words. Smog (**sm***oke + f***og**) is a well-recognized example of portmanteau.

That is, if *dognitary* itself were a recognized word listed in the dictionary, it would be portmanteau.

But, since *dognitary* is not in the dictionary yet (but it should be, since everyone knows what a *dognitary* is), it is a [sniglet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sniglet) instead. This term was coined by comedian Rich Hall in the 1980's.

Comment: Does a portmanteau *need* to appear in the dictionary to be a portmanteau, though? I would argue that 'Bennifer', while appearing (one hopes) in no dictionary, is still a portmanteau.

Answer (score 1):

I'll hazard a guess with **wordplay**, or more specifically, **pun**.

I'll accept that "pun" usually requires a play to be made on two words that sound *similar* to each other. Whether the similarity is sufficient to warrant the definition *pun* in the example you give is open to challenge.

Comment: I would agree that they fall under wordplay, but that is a fairly broad term and I was looking for something more specific.

Comment: yeah -- okay... I'm inclined to suggest a pun then, but only insofar as as the word with the substituted letter sounds similar to the original. I do agree that this might be stretching it though.

Answer (score 1):

I would call that a form of ***"mash-up"***, as defined by oxforddictionaries.com:

> noun, informal
>
> **a mixture or fusion of disparate elements**

Comment: Downvoter, no feedback?